# Moving old application to the middle of the screen

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to start an old application on a windows 10 machine (application is started via steam).

It all looks good except for one thing. The application was full screen in the past and when it starts up it is hanging borderless in the top left corner of my screen.

Is there any way to move it into the center? (tried right clicking on the icon ... no move.  tried <kbd>Win</kbd> + Arrow keys, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, + Arrow keys,...).

Comment: Did you do anything to make it run borderless? You could always try to check the game options and/or try to hit Ctrl+Enter to make it switch between fullscreen and window (if supported)

Comment: @Seth It's Alt-Enter usually do fullscreen/window switching.

Comment: @montonero thanks for correcting me, you're totally correct, it's Alt+Enter.

Comment: @Seth no alt+enter not working (game is dark forces 2 btw)